# How to execute sitecore command through powershell script

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions

I have a requirement that I have a button on the Ribbon like "Generate". If the Content author clicks on this Generate button, through Sitecore Command we are making some API calls, and based on the API response we create some Sitecore items.

Now my requirement is to make this activity automated through Powershell. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can follow the Ribbon documentation here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor#ribbon as well as the training included with SPE.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find the command that is being executed with the click of the Ribbon item.

Then, you can run the command in Powershell as below:

```
$commandContext = [Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext]::new()
// You will need to mention the full type for the command below
$returnValue = [My.Namespace.Ribbon.Command]::Execute($commandContext)
```

Hope this helps.